# How to use a return value from a function in a completely different function

Tags: python, function, return

I am writing a tic-tac-toe game and currently have the following functions:

```
 # Need: Board, Display Board, Play Game, Alternating Terms, Os, Xs, Wins, Losses

board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-", ]


def display_board():
    print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2])
    print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5])
    print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8])


def handle_turn():
    position = input("\nChoose a position from 1 to 9: ")
    position = int(position) - 1
    return position


def choose_player_marker(marker):
    player_marker = ''
    if marker == 'X' or marker == 'x':
        player_marker = 'X'
        return player_marker
    elif marker == 'O' or marker == 'o':
        player_marker = 'O'
        return player_marker


def opp_move():
    opp_marker = ''
    if choose_player_marker() == 'X':
        opp_marker = 'O'
    else:
        opp_marker = 'X'


def play_game():
    game_current = True
    display_board()
    marker = input("\nPlease choose a marker: 'X' or 'x' OR 'O' or 'o' : ")
    choose_player_marker(marker)
    opp_move()
    handle_turn()


play_game()
```

In the function `def choose_player_marker(marker):` I return `player_marker = 'X'` or `player_marker = 'O'`, depending on the condition.

I would like to use the resulting `'X'` or `'O'` in the function `def opp_move():` to determine which marker the opponent will choose. However, I am having difficulty in properly delegating the return statement. I tried using `marker` as the argument in the `def opp_move():` function and also have tried `if choose_player_marker(marker) == 'X'` to no avail.

How do I correctly handle the return statement from `def choose_player_marker(marker):` so that my `def opp_move():` function will be able to determine what marker the opponent will choose?

Comment: But where is `marker` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: You should pass the `marker` argument to the function, then you'll get _some kind_ of return value. Now you're just getting an error

Comment: @DanielRoseman ```marker``` is coming from the main function, it stores the user's input on if they want to play as X or O 

@ForceBru I've tried passing ```marker``` into ```opp_move()``` but just kept running into errors - for whatever reason it doesn't seem like ```choose_player_marker``` is not actually returning what I want it to return :(

Comment: *What* errors? Show the values you are using, the full context including where `marker` is coming from, and the *actual error you get*. Right now we can only guess what is going on.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If I run my code as displayed above, I get the error ```TypeError: choose_player_marker() missing 1 required positional argument: 'marker'```. My intentions are to pass the either returned ```player_marker``` variable from ```choose_player_marker()``` into ```opp_move()``` so that the ```opp_move()``` function can determine which marker the user has chosen and appropriately assign itself the opposite marker (If user is X, opp will by O)

Comment: Yes because you need to pass in marker, as explained by everyone here. In order to do so you have to have that value, which as far as we can tell you don't. Until you show your full code and explain what you want to happen there is no way to help you.

Comment: **Edit the question to show your full code**.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have edited my code to include the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now we can see your full code, the solution is simple.

You already call `choose_player_marker()` in `main`. You don't need to call it in `opp_move` as well. What you need to do instead is to capture the result when you call it in main, and then pass in the value to opp_move:

```
def opp_move(marker):
    if marker == 'X':
        opp_marker = 'O'
    else:
        opp_marker = 'X'
    return opp_marker


def play_game():
    game_current = True
    display_board()
    marker = input("\nPlease choose a marker: 'X' or 'x' OR 'O' or 'o' : ")
    marker = choose_player_marker(marker)
    opp_move(marker)
    handle_turn()
```

Now there are various other things wrong with this code, like the fact that handle_turn doesn't do anything useful, and that as others have pointed out choose_player_marker can be trivially replaced with a call to `marker.upper()`, but at least this should get you going.

Comment: Ah, okay, now I see - since ``marker`` is defined in ``play_game()`` I can just call it from within that function with the ``marker`` argument. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The function `choose_player_marker` doesn't *do* anything useful at present. If you give it an `X` it gives you back and `X`, if you give it an `O` it gives you back an `O`. The only use it has right now is converting lowercase x and o to uppercase X and O.

Thus there is no need to call it, because if we know the input (X) then we know the output (X).

Given the name: `choose_player_marker` I suspect you want either a different name (e.g. `normalise_player_marker()` or a different implementation, i.e. one that prompts for user-input asking the person if they want to be X or O?)

As for opp_move : There's no need to call `choose_player_marker`. If you know the player is `X` then you know the opponent is `O`, and vice versa. Thus I suspect you want something like this:

```
def normalise_marker(marker):
    if marker == 'X' or marker == 'x':
        return 'X'
    elif marker == 'O' or marker == 'o':
        return 'O'

def opp_move(player_marker):
    opp_marker = ''
    normed_marker = normalise_marker(player_marker)
    if normed_marker == 'X':
        opp_marker = 'O'
    else:
        opp_marker = 'X'
    # use opp_marker here
```

Note that in its current state normalise_marker doesn't handle the case of marker NOT being an X or O, and can be reduced to an even simpler implementation, but that is left as an exercise for you :)

Comment: Yes, I have a prompt for user input in the main function. ```choose_player_marker``` is so that regardless if the user inputs a lowercase character I would like it to be upper case since that X or O is the actual marker I will be using on the displayed tic tac toe board.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions but I am running into an TypeError telling me that I am missing 1 required positional argument: player_maker. From my understanding ```player_marker``` argument comes from my original code in my function ```choose_player_marker()``` but it either does not seem to be actually returning a X or an O or ```opp_move()``` does not seem to like the argument ```player_marker```

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with Python, but I guess it would make it more simple if the provided argument was set to lower case, the additional check for Capital case wouldn't be needed. Still You could probably shorten the code this way.

```
def choose_player_marker(marker):
    return marker.lower()

def opp_move(result):
if result == 'x':
    return 'o'
else:
    return 'x'

playerMarker = 'X'
res = choose_player_marker(playerMarker)
opp = opp_move(res)
print(result, opp)
```